# how to download json object as file from browser

Tags: javascript, json, html, html5-canvas

I have a json object, can I save it as a file on my desktop if yes how to do that and how to read that file back. I am working in javascript and html only.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
data = JSON.stringify(canvas)
```

My canvas is of fabric js if that helps understanding the problem. I'm just trying to save the canvas as json object and then want to download it as a file so it retains its functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/P9cEf/3/

jsfiddle, currently its working for online save and load on 2 different canvas I want to download and load from computer.

Comment: what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: well the ans below supports all the good browsers 
i dont really consider IE a good browser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the download attribute  of the anchor tag(I don't know how well supported it is) and the html5 file api.

```
<a href = "#" id = "save" download="data.json">Save Canvas 1</a>
Load Canvas<input type="file" id="load" />
```

```
$( "#save" ).click(function( event ) {
    this.href = 'data:plain/text,' + JSON.stringify(canvas1)
});
$( "#load" ).change(function( event ) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(){
        canvas2.loadFromJSON(this.result, canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2));
    }
    fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P9cEf/5/

---

Here is a version or new IE (IE11 at least)

```
$( "#save" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(canvas1)],{type:'application/json'});
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'data.json');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P9cEf/7/

Comment: Thanx musa 
Thanx really helps to give finish touch to my project thanx alot mate

Comment: I know this doesn't come as a surprise, but IE does not support it (yet?).

Comment: @Epistemex if they haven't done it by now I doubt they ever will, I also added a version for IE using an IE extension.

Answer (score 1):

#### Save

Update your save function to use this snippet to save the file to desktop:

- http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#console-save

#### Upload

- And then you would just need a form and server to upload to so that you can process a person's file they upload to a temporary location on the server, to load into your function that you already have made.
- What is available to you for server-side programming languages? Just Google how to upload a file in that language
- You can get contents of that file once it's uploaded via XHR request using jQuery ajax or vanilla JavaScript

Comment: cant i just read/upload the file in javascript directly from pc ?
according to my work flow the current user will save its work in file so he can work on it later 
he will open canvas page, press upload button to chose file from HIS system

Comment: Actually @mugheesilyas, poster above with the FileReader API is correct. You can use that. Here is the browser support using FileReader API http://caniuse.com/filereader

Comment: i am not saying he you are wrong, i up voted ur post aswell but musa`s post was to the point and precise with jsfiddle 
simple and neat but thanx for trying to help me ^_^