# Opening binary data as a file with a specific file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, binary, binaryfiles

I have a situation where I'm having to take binary data (for PDFs, word docs, etc) via ajax and allow users to download the file by clicking on a link.

Currently I am doing this by opening a new browser window with the binary data.

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,"+ binaryFileData);
```

This works for opening the file, but the file name generated is always the actual binary string and not anything human-readable.

[image]

Is there a way to give the opened file a specific name?

Comment: Kind of similiar http://stackoverflow.com/a/23572762/1353011

Comment: @jurgemaister - thank you. This appears to be what I was looking for. Trying out these solutions now.