# Make blob download work in FireFox and IE10/11

Tags: angularjs, blob

I have following code in angularjs which is supposed to receive an array of bytes from a web api method and then download the file.

This code is working perfectly in latest Google, but when I try it in latest FireFox the code executes without errors, but no download occurs. Also in IE 11, this download does not happen.

**Question**: How can I make this blob code work in latest FireFox and IE 10/11?

```
          return myDataService.getByteArray()
                .then(function (data) {

                var byteArray = new Uint8Array(data);
                var element = angular.element('<a/>');
                element[0].href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], 
                   { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));
                 element[0].download = 'mydatareport.pdf';
                 element[0].click();
           });
```

**UPDATE 1**:

In IE 10/11, all code executes without errors till element[0].click() is called, when following error happens.

[image]

Comment: IE does not support anchor download property.

Comment: @Musa, Is there a way to make anchor download work in IE 10/11?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570427/how-to-download-json-object-as-file-from-browser/23572762#23572762) shows a way to do it for ie 11